# Highcharts disable hover effect and select animation

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts and I want to disable the hover effect and select animation. I have tried the following:

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: false
            },
            select: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
},
```

But it didn't do the trick. This is how it looks like. There is absolut no need for hover effect (opacity: 0.2) and click animation:
[image: highchart hover & click state]

Answer (score 4):

You need to also disable `inactive` state and set `allowPointSelect` to `false`.

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      allowPointSelect: false,
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        },
        inactive: {
          enabled: false
        },
        select: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c9r68bmg/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.allowPointSelect